# Error:Cannot cast from Fragment to FragmentB

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have try many different way such as change `import.android.support.fragment` to `import.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but it still showing the error cannot cast from Fragment to FragmentB can anyone help me out and tell me where is the error

```
package interfragmet.sim7n;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communication{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public void respond(String data) {
    FragmentManager manager= getFragmentManager();
    FragmentB f2= (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB);
    f2.changeText(data); 
}
}
```

Comment: your activity and fragmentManger imports are incorrect, please see my post below.  Also you are using the wrong function to getFragmentManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using support v4 fragments then.

1. Your activity should be [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)
2. You must use the [getSupportFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29)
3. Your Fragment imports must look like this:

Imports:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; 
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've solve my error =D 
can you explain to me why it should be FragmentActivity?
what if in my mainactivity still have other activity, change to FragmentActivity will effect other activity or not?

Comment: the implementation details are beyond me, other than they are intended to be a compatible set (created to extend fragment support to prior Android API devices).  You can only call getSupportFragmentManager() from a fragmentActivity() so you have to use them together.  The only activities that need to be FragmentActivity are the ones that are hosting support Fragments.